# 90s or earlier TV series, man and woman with a time machine, liquid crystal

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'd like to know what this TV series was, if anyone recognises it.  I remember watching it when I was quite small, so it was on in the 1990s, in England.  Of course, that doesn't prove that it was *made* in the 1990s in England.  There was a man and a woman and they had a time machine.

I remember one episode where the "liquid crystal" in the time machine failed and the man said, "Well, that's the end of that".  The woman said, "Can't we get a new liquid crystal?" and he said, "Not unless you know where we can get twenty thousand pounds".  (I think he said pounds, not dollars, but I could be wrong.)  So then they go off to win the lottery (presumably the liquid crystal still had at least one more trip left in it), but naturally things don't go according to plan.

There were (what seemed to me at the time) amazing graphics when they travelled through time, of them hurtling along a tunnel with scenes from different times hurtling past.

Comment: Are you sure this was a series?  IE: Did you see more than one episode?

Comment: Well, I thought it was, but I only remember that one incident.  The set-up seems to imply that they'd been doing this for some time, but perhaps that was just an initial set-up for a one-off show?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a good chance that the show you are remembering was *Crime Traveller* made by the BBC. It was broadcast in the mid to late 1990's so fits your time period. It featured two main characters, a woman, played by Chloe Annette a who owned and operated the time machine and a man who was a police officer or detective. Together they used the time machine to solve crimes. There was actually an episode about the police officer character using the time machine to attempt to win the lottery. You can read episode synopsis on the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_Traveller#Episodes).

You can watch the episode about the lottery on YouTube here:

Comment: It's definitely Crime Traveller. The crystal failed in the series finale. Later on, the heroes discovered that an unscrupulous company had created a time machine of their own, and before it was destroyed at the end, the detective managed to steal its crystal. It was made clear that it was compatible with both time machines.

Comment: Amazing!  Well done!  I was beginning to think I'd imagined it.